# A question about subobjects of the unit in a rigid abelian tensor category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, tannakian-category

I have a question about Proposition 1.17 in Deligne and Milne, Tannakian Categories (see [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2018.pdf)), in the last 4 lines of the proof.
[image]

> I don't know how it follows from $U\otimes U\simeq U$ that $T=\ker(U\to U^\vee\otimes U)=0$ (or the largest subobject $T$ of $U$ such that $T\otimes U=0$ is $0$). Even if admitting this, I don't know why $\mathbb{1}=U\oplus U^\perp$ (or the SES at the beginning splits).

Could anyone give some details about these points? Thanks!

Comment: I think they key point is that you have a coevaluation map $\eta\colon 1\to U\otimes U^\vee$, an isomorphism $\delta\colon U\to U\otimes U$ and an evaluation map $\epsilon\colon U\otimes U^\vee\to 1$, so you have $(1\otimes\epsilon)\circ(\delta\otimes 1)\circ\eta\colon 1\to U$.  This will split the inclusion $U\to 1$.